# C# SQL Update CommandText and Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I created a simple SQL database that has one table, `tblCustomerInformation`, and three columns :

- FirstName,
- LastName,
- and Email.

I'm attempting to update it however when I run the code that I listed below the program does nothing.

It doesn't crash and give me errors it just does nothing.

I'm fairly certain that my `UPDATE` statement is correct. I'm not sure why this isn't working at this point.

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EWOODWARD-PC\SQL2012; Initial Catalog=CustomerGUI; Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblCustomerInformation SET LastName = @ln, Email = @em WHERE (FirstName = @fn)";

        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ln", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        //cmd.Parameters["@ln"].Value = txtLastName.Text;

        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@em", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        //cmd.Parameters["@em"].Value = txtEmail.Text;

        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@fn", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        //cmd.Parameters["@fn"].Value = txtFirstName.Text;


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", txtEmail.Text);

        Connection.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: FirstName = @fn is satisfied if you run it manually?  As a last resort capture a trace of the SQL call.

Comment: Is there an exception handler anywhere in the call stack when you run this? Are you sure there is no error and it is just being swallowed?

Comment: What values are you putting in your text boxes and what does the existing row in the database look like that you are trying to update?

Comment: Try the update statement as a select where LastName  = @ln and see if it returns any values.

Comment: This code looks ok, the most probable reason that you dont get an update, is  that you have no record with the FirstName you are providing

Comment: You're not trying to insert a new row using UPDATE, are you?

Comment: I'm a bit new to C# and SQL, but would this need a commit statement?

This looks like the Microsoft documentation on this topic, perhaps the example on the bottom of the page can be of help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx

I also noticed that their .open() method was implemented before their SQL statement. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Does `@fn` already exist in your table? If you don't have a matching row, the code is working properly, updating 0 rows due to not finding a match.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. The arrangement of `cmd.Parameters...` code should not be jumbled. Base it on the arrangement in your query.

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EWOODWARD-PC\SQL2012; Initial Catalog=CustomerGUI; Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblCustomerInformation SET LastName = @ln, Email = @em WHERE FirstName = @fn";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", txtFirstName.Text);

        Connection.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Have encountered this kind of error once.

Comment: First time I heard something like this. Are you sure you had problem that resolved after rearranging??

Comment: I have never heard of this and it doesn't make sense to me. One of the big advantages with parameters in dotnet is we finally have the ability to address them by name. Many other languages rely on the order of the parameters.